# file_get_contents, failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached

Tags: php, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

My codes is :

```
    if ( isset($_POST['gd_url']) && isset($_POST['accessToken'])) {
    $url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=".$fileId;
    // $url = $_POST['gd_url'];
    $name = $_POST['file'];
    $accessToken = $_POST['accessToken'];
    $opts = array(

            'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken                 
            )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $content = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    // echo $content;
    if (!empty($content)){

        file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/UPDRIVE/'.$name,$content);
    }
}
```

i try to add 
`'follow_location' => false` and `'max_redirects' => 101` but the same result

error :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B6ijT2xI7CfebEt3d3g1dndtZlU): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /.../uploadMediasSupdrive.php on line 24
```

if i change the ligne

```
$content = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

to

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

this work only with *.jpg file

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$param = $_REQUEST;
$oAuthToken = $param['oAuthToken'];
$fileId = $param['fileId'];
$getUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' . $fileId . '?alt=media';
$authHeader = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $oAuthToken;
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $getUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    $authHeader
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

file_put_contents($param['name'], $data);
```

this is the solution i found

Answer (score 0):

Since the other solutions didn't work for me I've found another solution.
In the $opts array, under 'http' I've added 'follow_location' = false.

```
$opts = [
    'http' => [
        'follow_location' => false
    ]
];
```

That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add this HTTP context options `max_redirects` :

see : https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

```
$arrContextOptions = array(
    "ssl" => array(
        // skip error "Failed to enable crypto" + "SSL operation failed with code 1."
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
         ),
     // skyp error "failed to open stream: operation failed" + "Redirection limit reached"
     'http' => array(
          'max_redirects' => 101,
          'ignore_errors' => '1'
      ),
           
  );

  $file = file_get_contents($file_url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

Obviously, I only use it for quick debugging purpose on my local environment. **It is not for production**.